# R: is there a pandas function map in R?

Tags: r

I want to map values from a named list in R to a dataframe. Is there a equivalent of pandas map function in R?

```r
list = (a=1, b=2)
df = data.frame(a)
```

`df.map(list)` in r?

I want to map values of list onto df.

Comment: Provide example input, and expected output.

Comment: Hi, pandas map is applied on a series, to replace values using a dictionary. is this what you need?

Comment: yes, that is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to map in pandas, it can be applied to a Pd series like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
x = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
LIST = {'a':1,'b':2}
x.map(LIST)

x = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
```

In R, you do:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("a","b","c"))
LIST = list(a=1,b=2)
as.character(LIST[match(df$x,names(LIST))])
"1"    "2"    "NULL"
```

or using dplyr from [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2505):

```
dplyr:::recode(df$x,!!!LIST)
[1]  1  2 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this which most closely resembles python's map function is the function recode from the dplyr library:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(numbers = c(1,2,3,1,1))

df <- df %>% mutate(tones=recode(numbers, 
                         '1'="do",
                         '2'="re",
                         '3'="mi"))
df
```

This will get you the following result:

```
  numbers tones
1       1    do
2       2    re
3       3    mi
4       1    do
5       1    do
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `apply` in R.

I'm trying to guess what you want here, assuming you're an R programmer who is more familiar with Python. Here's my guess:

```
l <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
lgt <- apply(l, 2, function(x) {x > 2})
```

Here, `lgt` will print out the following:

```
   [,1]  [,2]
a FALSE FALSE
b TRUE   TRUE
```

More importantly, what is going on here? Well, apply takes as an argument a *thing*, in this case a data frame, a number where `1` is "do this along rows" and `2` is "do this along columns" (this only matters if you're doing some reduction operation such as `sum`). Its third argument is a function, which we created in-place right there.

If you're stuck, an important tip is to be able to do `?apply` in the R prompt to get documentation for a function.